# atof() is returning ambiguous value

Tags: c, atof

I am trying to convert a character array into double in c using atof and receiving ambiguous output.

```
printf("%lf\n",atof("5"));
```

prints

```
262144.000000
```

I am stunned. Can somebody explain me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you #included the right headers?

Comment: Oops.. sorry for wasting your time. I reckon why it didn't flag an error when I didn't include stdlib.h . Thanks !

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure you have included the headers for both atof and printf. Without prototypes the compiler will assume they return `int` values. When that happens the results are undefined, since that doesn't match atof's actual return type of `double`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

#### No prototypes

```
$ cat test.c
int main(void)
{
    printf("%lf\n", atof("5"));
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -Wall -o test test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:3:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘printf’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
test.c:3:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘printf’ [enabled by default]
test.c:3:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘atof’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
test.c:3:5: warning: format ‘%lf’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]

$ ./test
0.000000
```

#### Prototypes

```
$ cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%lf\n", atof("5"));
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -Wall -o test test.c

$ ./test
5.000000
```

Lesson: Pay attention to your compiler's warnings.

Comment: And more generally, enable (and pay attention to) compiler warnings/errors!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar problem by having a decimal point and at least 2 zeros after the decimal point with

```
printf("%lf\n",atof("5.00"));
```